# How do I reset code coverage in IntelliJ, not hide it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

After running unit tests with code coverage, I used to get a pop up that asked if I would like to add to existing code coverage or reset it then add the new coverage.  I accidentally clicked on "do not ask again" and now it always just adds to existing code coverage.

But now I would like to clear my code coverage numbers, reset it to 0 lines covered.  When I search online and in SO all I find is answers to hide the code coverage, not reset it to 0 lines covered.  How exactly do I get the IDE to either ask me like it used to, if I would like to reset the code coverage after running a test, or how can I manually just reset the code coverage.  This is not about hiding it, this is about resetting it to 0 lines covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Coverage" and select the needed option.

Here is Jetbrains documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-coverage-measurement.html

[image]